# Thymeleaf client side validation

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and I working on a login form. I have found a simple example where there is login input text and password fields.

I have included the project in my system. When I click the login button without filling username and password section, a *please fill in details* ballon pops up. I have not configured it anywhere, but would like to know from it is getting popped up. Below is the code

```
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="form-group " align="right">
        </br> </br> </br> </br> </br></br> </br> </br> </br>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="form-heading">Log in</h2>

                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        Invalid username and password.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        You have been logged out.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="userName" class="form-control input-lg"
                           placeholder="UserName" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"
                           placeholder="Password" required="true"/>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                        <button class="btn btn-default" role="button">Log In</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have `required=true` Html5 will validate by default

Comment: tx a lot. Then I should have to look at the HTML5 tutorial as well. Can you please provide a good link and would like to know how to provide server side validation to thymeleaf

Comment: Not sure what are you expecting but if you remove `required=true` it will not validate client side. On submit it will call the controller and give you the result.